# Remove characters from beginning and end of string with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I need to remove characters from a string with jQuery.
The string is this right here...

```
{"id":"Spirits","name":"Spirits"}
```

I basically want the output to read Spirits (pulling from the "name" value).
I'm seeing a lot of answers for either beginning of string using subString or end of string.

But I'm not sure how to do both and ensure that if Spirits is Volvo or whatever, it accounts for that as well.

Any help is GREATLY appreciated.

Comment: Parse the JSON string and read its `name` property.

Comment: https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/javascript-remove-first-and-last-character-from-string

Comment: Does it absolutely need to be jQuery? Have you thought about using vanilla JS? Much simpler

Comment: Can you post a json you need too, pls?

Answer (score 0):

First, we parse the JSON string into a JSON object.

Next, we delete the key-value pair using the key "name".

Then, we recreate the JSON string from the JSON object with `stringify`.

Finally, we print the results:

```js
let jsonString = '{"id":"Spirits","name":"Spirits"}';
let json = JSON.parse(jsonString);
delete json["name"];
let output = JSON.stringify(json);
console.log(output);
```

If you want then to obtain just the word of that only element in your object you could:

```js
let jsonString = '{"id":"Spirits","name":"Spirits"}';
let json = JSON.parse(jsonString);
delete json["name"];

let output = JSON.stringify(json);
console.log(output);

output = Object.values(json)[0];
console.log(output);
```

Comment: Will that work if my output is EXACTLY {"id":"Spirits","name":"Spirits"} without the back slashes?

Comment: The back slashes are "escape characters". 
In side the variable `\"` becomes `"`. 
If you don't like them you can change from `let jsonString = "{\"id\":\"Spirits\",\"name\":\"Spirits\"}";` to this: `let jsonString = '{"id":"Spirits","name":"Spirits"}';` by using a single quote instead of the double quote.

Comment: Ah okay awesome. If I want to remove the beginning and end and just leave the Spirits from this...what would I use with subString?

Comment: https://codepen.io/Lummer/pen/NWXJqMg

Comment: @hellothree23 I modified to show you out to extract that only value in the object.

Answer (score 0):

Get result directly, Using object key and value if output is in JSON format

If Output is in string format then need to parse and then get data using object key and value

```js
// Get directly using output.name If getting JSON output
output = {"id":"Spirits","name":"Spirits"};
console.log('output Name : ', output.name);

// Parse and get output.name If getting String Output
output = '{"id":"Spirits","name":"Spirits"}';
output = JSON.parse(output);
console.log('output Name : ', output.name);
```

Comment: Amazing! that's perfect. Thanks Sahil!

Comment: you can upvote this answer if found useful, @hellothree23